# R bar plot: how to set specified number in y axis but do not change the distance between numbers in R

Tags: r

I want to customized the y axis to a certain number, but the distance in the y axis should not be changed accordingly like below figure. I tried different way, but failed. Basically, when I use the `axis(2, yseries)`, the y range will be changed.

The core I tried is like this:

```
yseries <- c(10,
             20,
             40,
             80,
             160,
             320,
             640,
             1280)

gm <- c(760, 640)
barplot(gm, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
# Y-axis
axis(2, at = yseries)
```

You can see the y axis is different from the attached figure (where the y ranges from 10 to 1280, but the distance in the y axis is not changed in this figure. I also want to make this kind of figure). Can you help me to figure out?

Thanks,

[This is the figure I want to replicate it in y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bguuJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the range of the y axis in the plot command, and use a log scale to get equal distances between multiples as follows:

```
barplot(gm, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", log="y", ylim = range(yseries))
axis(2, at = yseries,las=1)
```

[image]

As requested in the comments - a `ggplot2` solution.  This is a little tricky because using bar plots with log-scales isn't very natural.  The 'zero' disappears on the log-scale, so trying to set the limits within the `scale` function makes the columns disappear.  I use `coord_cartesian` to set the limits instead (data is different to previous plot):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
     geom_col() + 
     scale_y_log10(breaks=yseries)+
     coord_cartesian(ylim=range(yseries))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you help to explain it a little, why it work by using ```log = 'y'```. Also can you help figure out how can I do it using ggplot2, because ggplot2 give the better layout. I tried in this way but does not work. ```df <- data.frame(
  x = c('group01', 'group02'),
  y = c(20, 800))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(y = log(y)))
p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(yseries), max(yseries))) ```

Comment: I've added a ggplot solution.  Using a log scale means that multiples will be evenly spaced on the y-axis.  So, 10, 20 40, 80 etc will have even spaces between them.  That's almost the definition of logarithms!